# to_sql not updating table in ms server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, spyder

Hey so I have the below code I'm running where I'm pulling a table from a MS Sql Server table, running a bit of code and then trying to reimport it into another table within the same database. Running this in spyder

It runs all the way through, but when I

```
select * from pythontest
```

on the SQL Server, the table comes out blank. Is there anything that is standing out as not working?

```
## From SQL to DataFrame Pandas
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine



sql_conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=njsrvnav1;"
                      "Database=cornerstone;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
query = "SELECT [c1], [c2], [c3] from projectmaster"
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
df = df[:100]
con = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://username:pword@serverName:1433/cornerstone?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
df.to_sql('dbo.pythontest', con, if_exists='replace')
con.dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with  `pymysql` :

```
conn = pymysql.connect(
host='',
port=
user='',
passwd='',
db='',
charset='utf8mb4')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table ",
conn)
df.head(2)
```